# Unable to release memory bytes buffer

Tags: go, bytebuffer

Go 1.18.1

pprof report

```
 3549.93kB 49.73% 49.73%  3549.93kB 49.73%  src/lag_monitor.PublishLagMetricToDataDog
     514kB  7.20% 56.93%      514kB  7.20%  bufio.NewWriterSize
  512.88kB  7.18% 64.11%   512.88kB  7.18%  encoding/pem.Decode
  512.69kB  7.18% 71.30%  1536.98kB 21.53%  crypto/x509.parseCertificate
  512.50kB  7.18% 78.48%   512.50kB  7.18%  crypto/x509.(*CertPool).AddCert
```

This piece of code appears to not release memory and based on pprof, the beloew function is the one consuming most memory.Memory graph
[image]

```
func caller() {
 events := make([]string, 0)
 //....
 PublishLagMetricToDataDog(ctx, strings.Join(events, ","))
}

func PublishLagMetricToDataDog(ctx context.Context, events string) error {
msg := `{
    "series": [%v]
}`
b := []byte(msg)
resp, err := http.Post("https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series?api_key="+env.GetDataDogKey(), "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(b))
if err != nil {
    logger.Error(ctx, "Error submitting event to datadog, err = ", err)
    return err
}
logger.Info(ctx, resp)
return nil
}
```

Above function is called in a loop. Since there are no global variables, and no reference to the byte slice from PublishLagMetricToDataDog, I am not able to pinpoint the memory leak. I read about Reset() and Truncate(), but this does not release the underlying memory.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there's no reason to use `b := []byte(msg)`. Use `strings.NewBuffer(msg)` instead of `bytes.NewBuffer(b)`

Comment: The problem is not the buffer, the garbage collection is not somehow missing your byte slice. The only way to cause an apparent memory leak like this is to have goroutines which are not returning. Are you reading and closing `resp.Body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close the response body for every http response you receive. Not doing so will potentially lead to resource leaks, such as the one you've observed.

Solution:

```golang
    resp, err := http.Post("https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series?api_key="+env.GetDataDogKey(), "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(b))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(ctx, "Error submitting event to datadog, err = ", err)
        return err
    }
    logger.Info(ctx, resp)
    _ = resp.Body.Close() // <--- Add this
    return nil
}
```

Comment: a dummy question, why not 'defer' it right after the HTTP request ?

Comment: Because there's no reason to defer the last statement of a function.